# Wordpress featured image as background with default image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, loops

I have some code that uses a posts featured image as the background of a DIV...

```
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ):
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
endif; ?>
<div class="news-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>); background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-color: #000; background-position: center center; background-size: cover;">
```

Pretty simple, but I need to set a default image on this background for any posts that do NOT have a featured image set.

Is that possible by modifying my above code?

For example...

If post has featured image - show it.

If post does not have featured image - show default.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that, I did some rought snippet, hope you can get the info from my comments :)

```
<?php 

// first you have to define and save your default image somewhere,, save it in options table for ex.. like this:

add_option( 'my_default_pic', 'http://www.website.com/image/jpg', '', 'yes' );


// then on page or template use like this
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ){
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0]; 
} else {
    $image = get_option( 'my_default_pic' );
}
?>

<div class="news-image" style="#000 no-repeat center center background: url(<?php echo $image; ?>);"> 
    body = lorem ipsum
</div>
```

that's it :)

hth,

edit: inserted example image path

Comment: that shows the featured image but not the default. Can you add to your code a real world link to show me where the default image goes? If image is http://website.com/image/jpg how does that fit in your code?

Comment: I have hardcoded url in `add_option` on the first line.. hope that can help you

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't show a default image for posts with no featured image set. The code puts nothing in the URL field like this :  style="background-image: url(); : the URL parameter is blank.

Comment: just wanted to check in and see if you had any thoughts as to why the url parameter is returning empty?

Comment: hi @lowercase I edited this and tested this peace of code and it works as I expected .. do not know why you get empty string.. that does not sound right to me..